# Explanation of mapper program for search in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am new to hadoop, so i am having difficulty in understanding the programs a little. So, If someone can help me in understanding this mapper program ?

```
package SearchTxn;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class MyMap extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text>{

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String Txn = value.toString();
            String TxnParts[] = Txn.split(",");
            Double Amt = Double.parseDouble(TxnParts[3]);
            String Uid = TxnParts[2];           
            if(Uid.equals("4000010") && Amt>100)
            {
                context.write(null, value); 
            }           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code basically filters lines in which `Uid` (second column in your csv) is "4000010" and `Amt` (I guess for amount, third column in your csv) is greater than 100.

Comment: But what is the meaning of context.write(null, value);?
because when we were doing the word count we were putting 
IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1)
Text outkey = new Text(word)
Later performing context.out(outkey,value)  but here in this above code i am not getting what is happening in output line i.e. the context one.

Comment: @KuldeepSingh so you should include this in your question. Writing `null` as the key when you are using the `TextOutputFormat` makes the format only write the value without a key/value seperator.

Answer (score 0):

Along with answer from @Thomas Jungblut, below line of your program says about Mapper class overall input and output. Here nothing is retuned as a `key` but Text as a `value`.

```
public class MyMap extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text>{
```

So are the parameters in write method.

```
context.write(null, value);
```

Its not always necessary to write key for serialization from Mapper class. As per your use case , either key or value or both can be written to `context.write` method.

Comment: It means that we are taking key as null and whole line as value ?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Not sure about your use case, but if you are extracting something out of value. Then you should send them out of mapper. Here value is carry forwarding as is after some validation.

Comment: yeah, this is a program for searching a particular record with some id and amount. This result will be fed into the reducer. 
So, here we have taken key as null and a full line or say row as value ?

Comment: Go ahead then, and if you think this answer has solved or answered your question properly. Please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? for more information.